# How to change Lightslider position to horizontal for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#vertical').lightSlider({
            gallery:true,
            item:1,
            vertical:true,
            verticalHeight:700,
            vThumbWidth:50,
            thumbItem:8,
            thumbMargin:-250,
            slideMargin:0,
            responsive : [
                {
                    breakpoint:800,
                    settings: {
                        vertial:false,
                        item:1,
                        slideMove:1,
                        slideMargin:6,
                        thumbItem:16,
                        thumbMargin:-250,
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
```

That is not working for me. Why ?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the code syntax you are writing - it isn't just normal Javascript right?
In case it is feasible for you I'd recommend using nativ CSS media queries.

Comment: Several questions and answers on how to detect a mobile browser, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser while is not always infallible, i would start there

Comment: It's normal Javascript